# I need to change decimal commas to points in the columns of a txt file

Tags: python, converters, txt

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
date/time: ,16/02/2023,10:48 a.m.
Run 1

time    Velocity 2
0,000000    1,992073E-1
0,016667    1,983866E-1
0,033333    1,982413E-1
0,050000    1,982486E-1
0,066667    1,979145E-1
0,083333    1,980452E-1
0,100000    1,981251E-1
0,116667    1,981542E-1
0,133333    1,977039E-1
0,150000    1,979653E-1
0,166667    1,979435E-1
0,183333    1,979000E-1
0,200000    1,979290E-1
0,216667    1,979072E-1
0,233333    1,980162E-1
```

I need to replace the commas with points in order to analyze it.

I´ve tried with a code my teacher gave me

```py
def load_data_with_comma(archive):
    def convert_number_with_comma(x: bytes) -> float:
        return float(x.decode().replace(",", "."))

    return np.loadtxt(archive, converters={0: convert_number_with_comma})
```

but it returns

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'date/time:'
```

what can I try?

Comment: the data is divided into two columns, one with time and the other with velocity

Comment: You may want to **skip** the first 3-4 lines as they are a different format.

Comment: Yes, but obviously you have a header.  You need to tell numpy to skip the header.  `loadtxt` has a `skiprows` parameter designed specifically for this.